# Display object on page in a different location based on time of day

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I'm looking at placing an object on a page in a different position based upon time of day. Specifically, I would like to have an image of the sun on the page. I would like it to move across the page based upon what time of day it is for the user. Any ideas or suggestions? It's probably been done before I imagine. I tried googling it and found some really really old results but nothing recent.

Comment: this link relaly explains well about position http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting idea.. +1 VoteyDisciple, I just decided to write a small mock up on it.

new Date() returns date/time for the local machine.

```
var date = new Date();

var hour = date.getHours();

if (hour == 0) { // when it's 12:00am
   $(foo).css({left: ___, top: ___}); // fill in position
   $(foo2).css({left: ___, top: ___}); // fill in position

} else if (hour == 1) { // when it's 1:00am
   $(foo).css({left: ___, top: ___}); // fill in position
   $(foo2).css({left: ___, top: ___}); // fill in position

} else if (hour == 2) { // when it's 2:00am

} ......
```

Just a simple thought how to get this going.. You can position other elements depending on the hour of the day as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use absolute positioning: `position: absolute;` in CSS, with `top: ___;` and `left: ___;` properties to position the object on the page.

You can change those properties easily using JavaScript. Since you tagged your question as using jQuery, you could use simply `$(foo).css({left: ___, top: ___});`

And of course, JavaScript's `Date` object can give you information about the current date and time.

Comment: Would `$(foo).css({'left':'___', 'top':'____'})` work and be slightly more concise? (Not a criticism, just a question; I may well have missed something important.)

Comment: that's cool. but i'm looking at moving the sun across the page, too. absolute positioning would be the perfect solution for placing the sun. but i'm hoping to move the sun as well.

Comment: @Jason Shultz: That's what the jQuery is for. You can change the `left` and `top` attributes whenever you want using JavaScript. @David Thomas: Good catch; I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! I see what you're saying now. :)